# Is ActiveMQ Artemis Java JPMS (Java Platform Module System) compatible?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis, java-platform-module-system

When I try running

```
"[path_to]\jdk-15.0.2+7_zip_unzip\bin\jdeps.exe" --multi-release="11" --ignore-missing-deps --module-path="[path_to]\my.test.module\target\modules"  --generate-module-info out "[path_to]\my.test.module\target\modules\artemis-server-2.16.0.jar"
```

I get something like this

```
Error: Modules artemis.core.client and artemis.server export package org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.settings.impl to module org.apache.tomcat.embed.websocket
```

I just want to know if ActiveMQ Artemis is JPMS compatible. If so, then what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: +1, but I had sensed this some time back that it's better to ask these questions on individual trackers of the libraries. gets much faster attention from the library owners and plus if they are unable to respond, you can infer how actively is the library maintained at present.

Comment: aside: do ensure, that  `artemis.core.client` and `artemis.server` are not explicit dependencies required by your code and if that has any alternative suggested.

Comment: What version of `jdeps` are you using? I'm using OpenJDK 11 and it chokes on `--ignore-missing-deps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any explicit effort to make ActiveMQ Artemis JPMS compatible so any existing compatibility would almost certainly be coincidental. Feel free to open [a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS) to request compatibility.

FWIW, at least [one problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3077) has already been identified.